# Connecting Azure Communication Services with MS DevTunnel

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-communication-services

I am following the official Azure communication-services-python-quickstarts repo on GitHub, which instructs users to register an EventGrid subscription resource using a Webhook to process the IncomingCall Event which points to my DevTunnel URI.

Link to guide used.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-python-quickstarts/tree/main/callautomation-openai-sample

I have done such but our resource fails to deploy. I followed the guide step by step, however when I get to the final step where I deploy the EventGrid Subscription, I get this error (error below). I believe Azure is not able to communicate with our Devtunnel for whatever reason. I am very new to Azure and would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Deploying Event Subscription: test X
Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation" "message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for https://zkd74chk.use.devtunnels.ms:8080/. Http POST request timed out.